# Having troubles writing a main method which tests if my LinkedList function work properly

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

My question focuses on the main method of this program. I'm having troubles creating the main menu to execute functions within LinkedLists. What's an efficient way to pass in two head pointers with one pointer pointing to an empty list? This code takes a node off the passed in unsorted LinkedList and inserts it into an empty LinkedList. The following code sorts the linked list (in ascending order) using insertion sort and returns new head pointer of the sorted linked list.

```
package insertionsortlinkedlist;

public class InsertionSortLinkedList {

public static LinkedListNode sorted_insert(
        LinkedListNode head,
        LinkedListNode node) {

    if (node == null) {
        return head;
    }

    if (head == null || node.data <= head.data) {
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    }

    LinkedListNode curr = head;

    while (curr.next != null
            && (curr.next.data < node.data)) {

        curr = curr.next;
    }

    node.next = curr.next;
    curr.next = node;

    return head;
}

public static LinkedListNode insertion_sort(
        LinkedListNode head) {

    LinkedListNode sorted = null;
    LinkedListNode curr = head;

    while (curr != null) {

        LinkedListNode temp = curr.next;

        sorted = sorted_insert(sorted, curr);

        curr = temp;
    }

    return sorted;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    LinkedListNode list = new LinkedListNode();
    list.head = new LinkedListNode(29);
    list.head.next = new LinkedListNode(23);
    list.head.next.next = new LinkedListNode(82);
    list.head.next.next.next = new LinkedListNode(11);
    //System.out.println(list.data);
    System.out.println("Given Linked list");
    list.printList(list.head);

}
```

}

Comment: Your question is unclear. It looks like you can just call `insertionSort(head)` from your `main` function. I don't see where you need to pass two pointers to any function from `main`.

Comment: The method sorted_insert() takes in 2 parameters. Both parameters are pointers to LinkedList. The first parameter represents a pointer to the head of a populated linked list (29->23->82->11) as shown in my main method.The 2nd parameter starts as an empty Linked List pointing to null. Here is how the algorithm works.
While the Original list is not empty:
   Remove an element (say 'X') from the Original list.
   Insert 'X' at the correct sorted position in the Sorted list the second linked list represents the sorted list to be returned. That's why I have 2 linked lists as parameters.

Comment: But the `main` method doesn't need to call `sorted_insert`. It just needs to call `insertionSort`, like this: `LinkedListNode result = insertionSort(list);` And then output the result.

Comment: InsertionSort is the class, not the method that needs to execute the function.

Comment: Okay, so the method is called `insertion_sort`. Pardon my error.